# ImportError: cannot import name RemovedInDjango19Warning

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-allauth

I'm on Django 1.8.7 and I've just installed Django-Allauth by cloning the repo and running pip install in the app's directory in my webapp on the terminal. Now when I run manage.py migrate, I get this error:

```
➜src git:(master) ✗ python manage.py migrate
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        from django.apps import apps
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from .config import AppConfig
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 6, in <module>
        from django.utils.module_loading import module_has_submodule
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 4, in <module>
        from importlib import import_module
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 6, in <module>
        from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango19Warning
    ImportError: cannot import name RemovedInDjango19Warning
    ➜  src git:(master) ✗
```

[image]

I've checked and I'm still on django 1.8.7 so it wasn't accidently upgraded.

Comment: that's an interesting error, as far as I can tell no such exception even exists in the Django project, at least my searches of RemovedInDjango19Warning came up empty.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes It exists in [Django 1.7](https://github.com/django/django/blob/82e651e9485fb7d6a64853c941e804fafb9b7606/django/utils/deprecation.py#L5) and [Django 1.8](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1261c49690e25c9887f88b7d7f391764f01e1992/django/utils/deprecation.py#L14).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@MaxRah This is caused by conflicts in Django versions. As mentioned by others, you will have to remove `pip uninstall django` and reinstall your preferred version: `pip install django==1.9` This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error while trying to use cron-jobs on python (using kronos library)

```
#getting error while trying to run kronos cron job
python manage.py runtask complain
```

as @ olivrg metioned this fixed the issue (reinstall django in my case i was using version 1.8.X so i upgraded to 1.9X)

```
sudo pip uninstall django

sudo pip install django==1.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Your installation is corrupt, your traceback does not match the code from version 1.8.7 (`from importlib import import_module` is on [line 8](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.7/django/utils/module_loading.py), not line 4). You need to uninstall Django and do a clean install.

I would highly recommend to set up a virtual environment for your Django project, using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). This is a de facto standard to separate different python environments on your system. The corruption likely occurred because different projects tried to install different versions of Django in your system-wide site packages.

Comment: Thanks. I am actually using a virtualenv. I think something happened while I was installing allauth to cause the corruption. Do you have a useful link on how to do a clean django uninstallion?

Comment: @MaxRah Just uninstall, remove the `django` directory in your `site-packages` if it still exists, and reinstall.

Comment: Thanks @knbk reinstalling django fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install -Ur requirements.txt`

***Use This Command It Will Work***