# Error while running ./runtests.py from django

Tags: python, django

1. I took fork from https://github.com/django/django
2. Running in python3 virtual env
3. When I run ./runtests.py inside the tests folder I am getting this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./runtests.py", line 19, in 
    from django.utils.deprecation import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'RemovedInDjango20Warning'

Tried running on django 2.0 and django 1.9

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./runtests.py", line 19, in 
    from django.utils.deprecation import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'RemovedInDjango20Warning'

I should be able to run all the test cases

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name RemovedInDjango19Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34557091/importerror-cannot-import-name-removedindjango19warning)

Comment: nope, as i mentioned. I tried with both *django 2.0* and *django 1.9*

Comment: And you have installed both versions. So follow by the instruction from this link

Comment: Nju doesn't make sense. @moderator are you listening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that `runtests.py` is running the tests for Django itself, not for your project. If you want to run the tests for your project, then perhaps you want to run `Python manage.py test` instead.

If you do want to run the Django tests, then note that `runtests` is designed to be run with Django from the same checkout.

The [readme](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.4/tests/README.rst) gives the following instructions to install the checked-out Django. I recommend using a fresh virtual environment for this. First activate your virtual environment and cd into the repository. Then run:

```
$ cd tests
$ python -m pip install -e ..
$ python -m pip install -r requirements/py3.txt
$ ./runtests.py
```

Note that `RemovedInDjango20Warning` was only used in Django 1.10 and 1.11. If you try to import it in Django 1.9 or 2.0 then you’ll get an import error. That’s why you should run the tests against the same version of Django that they were written for.